# How to replace a missing month using jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays

This is my json_encode output

```
  $result = '[{ MFG_NAME: "ABC", CONCATED_MKT_SHARE: "01-OCT-14|0.59" },
        { MFG_NAME: "XYZ", CONCATED_MKT_SHARE: "01-OCT-14|0.87" },
        { MFG_NAME: "ABC", CONCATED_MKT_SHARE: "01-NOV-14|0.25" },
        { MFG_NAME: "XYZ", CONCATED_MKT_SHARE: "01-NOV-14|0.67" },
        { MFG_NAME: "ABC", CONCATED_MKT_SHARE: "01-DEC-14|0.10" },
        { MFG_NAME: "XYZ", CONCATED_MKT_SHARE: "01-DEC-14|0.03" }]';
```

This is what I have done in jquery

```
 $(function () {        
   var data = new Array();
   data = <?php echo $result; ?>;   
   var MFG_NAME = [];
   var DATE = [];
   var MKT = [];

data.forEach(function(item) {
var parts = item.CONCATED_MKT_SHARE.split("|");
var i = MFG_NAME.indexOf(item.MFG_NAME);
if (i == -1) {
    MFG_NAME.push(item.MFG_NAME);
    DATE.push([parts.shift()]);
    MKT.push([+parts.shift()]);
}
else {
    DATE[i].push(parts.shift());
    MKT[i].push(+parts.shift());
}
});
});
```

There are some months missing for ABC and for XYZ. Is there any way to replace the missing months with the month that has missed, so that I get all 12 months and also 12 mktshare values replacing the concatenated value with 0

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cz6bks5d/1/ ?

Comment: I would leave the data as is. A missing data point may have a very different meaning to a data point of 0. If you are going to massage the data make the value `null`. I come from a background of handling financial market data, we would never ad a value on the data end to replace missing data as that is in itself meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like

```
$(function () {
    var months = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']

    var data = new Array();
    data = JSON.parse('[{"MFG_NAME":"ABC","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-MAR-14|0.74,01-APR-14|0.58,01-MAY-14|0.21,01-JUN-14|0.22,01-JUL-14|0.24,01-SEP-14|0.96,01-DEC-14|0.21,01-AUG-14|0.34"},{"MFG_NAME":"XYZ","CONCATED_MKT_SHARE":"01-MAR-14|0.44,01-MAY-14|0.82,01-JUN-14|0.71,01-AUG-14|0.22,01-JUL-14|0.24,01-SEP-14|0.96,01-DEC-14|0.21,01-AUG-14|0.34"}]');

    var x = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var mfg = data[i],
            share = mfg.CONCATED_MKT_SHARE;
        for (var j = 0; j < months.length; j++) {
            if (share.indexOf('-' + months[j] + '-') == -1) {
                share += ',01-' + months[j] + '-14|0.0';
            }
        }
    }


    var dlen = data.length;
    var cmname = new Array();
    var cmdate = new Array();
    var crank = [];
    var mktshare = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < dlen; i++) {
        cmname[i] = data[i].MFG_NAME;
        shar = new Array();
        shar = data[i].CONCATED_MKT_SHARE.split(',');
        shlen = shar.length;
        shrk = new Array();
        shard = new Array();
        for (j = 0; j < shlen; j++) {
            shaak = new Array();
            shaak = shar[j].split('|');
            shrk[j] = shaak[0];
            shard[j] = parseFloat(shaak[1]);

        }
        cmdate[i] = shrk;
        mktshare[i] = shard;
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cz6bks5d/)

Comment: The structure of $result is changed due to changes made in database query can you please give the same logic for the new output  $result